# add new XML document through SolrJ

Tags: java, xml, solr, solrj

I know that import and indexing XML files in Solr is possible in 2 ways:
-)DIH;
-)bin/post method via bash console.

Is possible to do that using some API's of SolrJ, using Java?

How can I add a doc, like this below, as a new XML document?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            SolrServerException {
        HttpSolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(
                "http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts");
    SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc.addField("cat", "book");
    doc.addField("id", "book-" + i);
    doc.addField("name", "The Legend of the Hobbit part " + i);
    client.add(doc);
```

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible why dont you just post your xml file to solr server.

```
SolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
    ContentStreamUpdateRequest req = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
    req.addFile(new File("myxml.xml"));
    req.setParam(ExtractingParams.EXTRACT_ONLY, "true");
    NamedList<Object> result = server.request(req);
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

solr is smart enough to understand extention of file, extract and index it  :)

Comment: I'm using Solr 5.2.1, and the method `req.addFile(new File("myxml.xml"))` and `req.setParam(ExtractingParams.EXTRACT_ONLY, "true")` are wrong. A fundamental question: when I add a new XML file, this file has to match with some fields of the _schema.xml_ file of the collection in which I want to insert the new XML, or can I add a new file XML without following any type of configurations? P.S. I'm new about Solr, so I'm sorry if I'm asking you trivial questions.